# Install Multiple Instances of Windows Service using WiX Toolset

Tags: msi, windows-installer

I want to install an msi multiple times on a machine. The purpose of this is to install multiple instances of a service with different service names.

I am able to install one service with a user defined service name, but when I try to install a second one it shows me the repair/remove dialog due to the fact that the product code already exists. Is there a work around for this (Other than Instance Transforms)

I have a weird requirement of having to use the msi double click install only

Answer (score 0):

Each separate service should be either:

1. A separate product with different product codes.
2. If the services are related, they can be separate features within an individual product.  You can then add or remove features within the individual product on demand as a reconfiguration of the overall product.

See also: [Installing Multiple Instances of Products and Patches](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/installing-multiple-instances-of-products-and-patches)

Are you providing the service name via a public property argument to the MSI?  If so, that's not what MSI is intended for.